# How should i execute and get the result of a query which is stored in a column as a data value

Tags: sql, sap-iq

How do I execute a Sybase query which is stored in a column of another Sybase table?

Suppose that "SELECT COLa FROM TABLE_A" is stored in a column called 'command' in a separate table (table_log). I want to find a way that allows me to execute this query and get the answer.

Comment: I can't think of any excuse for designing it like this, unless you really want your system to appear on The Daily WTF some day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try looking for

```
execute immediate
```

I'm not familiar with sybase but in Oracle it would be something like the following:

```
declare
    query varchar2(1000);
begin
    select val from saved_query into query;
    execute immediate query;
    commit;
end;
```

Comment: thank you very much i think this will help me a lot, thank you again
:-)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
create table test_table(f1 varchar(64))
insert into test_table values( "select getdate()" )
go
declare @myvar varchar(30)
select @myvar=f1 from test_table
execute(@myvar)
go
```